# Install Php8-dev on php:8.0.1-fpm-alpine

Tags: php, php-8

With Docker, i try to build some php extensions from sources.

In order to do that, i install php8-dev, but, after that, it's install also php8, so i have two different build of php8, causing break ldd for the .so

```
# php -v
PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2021 21:27:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans

# php8 -v
PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan 10 2021 13:43:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Below, a sample of my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.1-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community php8-dev 

WORKDIR /srv
```

Any idea ?

Comment: did u solve it?